# How to make an editor with live preview and a cursor

Tags: javascript, html, css, markdown

I want to make a live editor similar to https://stackedit.io/app#. It's not for markdown but some custom format.

It splits the page in two, on one side, user edits the content. On the other side, content is parsed and turned into html, some scripts are run on it and presented.

What is one simple way to achieve this?
Is the editor a text box, or regular html.
What is the editor cursor made out of?

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: This question is too broad.  Asking how to make an "editor" is not a simple, concise, question.

Comment: This seems to help https://www.w3.org/wiki/Web_Editing_APIs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a very basic text editor using this HTML API 'contenteditable"
using other apis like

- document.execCommand('bold')
- document.execCommand('underline')

you can add much more

this is a little demo of the APIs :

```js
document.querySelector('#bold').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.execCommand('bold');
});


document.querySelector('#udl').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.execCommand('underline');
});
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">TYPE WHAT YOU WANT !!</div>
<button id="bold">BOLD</button>
<button id="udl">Under Line</button>
```

and this line of HTML I got from the website you provided so this API

```
<pre class="editor__inner markdown-highlighting" tabindex="0" contenteditable="true" style="padding: 10px 25px 43px;" spellcheck="false"><div class="cledit-section">
```

is the core but for such a web app to be built it's very complicated but there are so many js libs that can help you, you don't have to reinvent the wheel